# Permutation of the swedish word "matematik"

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have three questions and (I think) I have solved two of them so far. First one is

1. Calculate the number of words from the word "matematik" with switching order of the letters

this I got to be 45360 as its $\frac{9!}{2!2!2!}$

2. calculate how many of these words contain both a $t$ in the end AND the start

this I got to $\frac{7!}{2!2!}$ or $1260$

3. How many of these words contain the sequence "mat" atleast one place in the word

I do not really know how to approach this as it is 2 sequences of "mat" that can be made from the word "matematik" since m, a, t appear twice.

Answer (score 4):

The number of words that contain at least one "mat" may be evaluated by treating one set of the three constituent letters as a "macro letter". Then all $7$ letters are different and the number of admissible words is $7!$.

From this, the inclusion/exclusion principle says we must subtract the number of words with two "mat"s. Here, both macros "mat" are the same, so the number of words is $\frac{5!}2$. Subtracting gives the result as $7!-\frac{5!}2=4980$.

Comment: Okay thanks I thought I was multiplying by a factor 2 since the string appears twice in some words and thus have to be excluded. Regarding q1 and q2; these are correct right? I do not need a factor 3! as the other comment states?

Comment: @user2661923 regarding Q1 and Q2 though. I do not really see why this is true.

Comment: +1 nice elegance re the last part of your answer.

Comment: @user2661923 what do you mean exactly with re the last part of your answer? For why I do not see this read this as an example:  https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-calculate-permutations-of-a-word this and multiple other sources I have found explains it in this way. I really do not see why the factor of 3! is relevant.

Comment: @mathstudent23 **my bad**.  I misread your answer.  You are absolutely right.  I will correct my answer.

Comment: @user2661923 haha that is all good. Thanks for weighing in, though!

Comment: May I ask why it is $5!$ over $2$?

Answer (score 2):

Q3

Easiest to over-count and substract back.

"mat" can start in any one of 7 places.  Once it starts, the other 6 letters can be in any order.

$A_1 = 7 \times 6! = 7!$

"mat...mat" possibilities re above have each been counted twice, so must be enumerated and deducted.

if 1st "mat" starts on position 1, 4 possibilites for 2nd "mat" to start.

if 1st "mat" starts on position 2, 3 possibilites for 2nd "mat" to start.

if 1st "mat" starts on position 3, 2 possibilites for 2nd "mat" to start.

if 1st "mat" starts on position 4, 1 possibilites for 2nd "mat" to start.

Total of 10 "mat...mat" placements.  With each placement
need 3! factor re (again) permuting 3 odd letters.

$A_2 = 10 \times 3!.$

Final answer = $A_1 - A_2.$

---

**Addendum**

Per OP's request.

Explanation for various methods of counting the # of ways that the "mat...mat..."
string can occur.

Once you compute the # of ways that a "...mat..." string can occur, you then have to
deduct the # of ways that the "mat...mat..." string can occur.  This deduction
is needed because in the original computation, each of these
"mat...mat..." occurrences was **double-counted.**

The (kludgy) approach that I took was to reason that the 1st "mat" string
would have had to begin somewhere in positions 1 through 4.  I then manually
determined that there were 10 different possible placements of "mat...mat...".

I then reasoned that each placement must be multiplied by $3!$, because the
three odd letters can permute.

Parcly Taxel also concluded that these "mat...mat..." placements must be
enumerated to compensate for their being overcounted.

His (elegant) approach to counting them was totally different than mine.

He reasoned as follows:

Suppose, instead of considering that you have 9 letters, you **pretend** that
you have **5 units**, as listed below:

Unit-1 = "mat" 
Unit-2 = "mat" 
Unit-3 = "e" 
Unit-4 = "i" 
Unit-5 = "k"

Then you should **also pretend** that **instead** of having **9 letter-positions**
you have **5 - unit-positions**.

Then, you surmise that these 5 "units" can be permuted in any one of $5!$ ways
among these 5 unit-positions.

Then, you recognize that because Unit-1 and Unit-2 are **identical**, you have
(ironically) double-counted the # of possible **distinct** placements of these
5 units.

For example, the placement

Unit-1, Unit-2, Unit-3, Unit-4, Unit-5

has been counted separately from

Unit-2, Unit-1, Unit-3, Unit-4, Unit-5

This means that the correct # of distinct ways of permuting these 5 units,
given that Unit-1 and Unit-2 are identical is

$$\frac{5!}{2}.$$

So, you have two completely different (but both valid) approaches to counting
how many "mat...mat..." placements must be deducted.

My way was $10 \times 3!.$  His way was $\frac{5!}{2}.$

Comment: Would you explain how $5!$ over $2$ is the ammount we have to exclude by?

Comment: @mathstudent23 See the addendum that I just added to my answer.

Comment: Oh I see but the factor of 2 is throwing me off a bit.  I see we have to deduct an ammount from $7!$ equal to $5!$ but not sure of why we divide by $2!$

Comment: Because otherwise, when enumerating the amount to be deducted, we are **incorrectly** counting as separate possibilities :[unit-1][unit-2][unit-3][unit-4][unit-5] and [unit-2][unit-1][unit-3][unit-4][unit-5].  More explicitly, we are incorrectly counting twice [mat-1][mat-2][e][i][k] and [mat-2][mat-1][e][i][k].

Comment: Ahh so Half of these are "identical" in this sense because the "mat" string is actually identical?

Comment: @mathstudent23 Exactly, you got it.